# PowerShell Passing Multiple Parameters to a Class Method Fails

Tags: function, powershell, variables, methods, parameters

I have a weird PowerShell problem. I am trying to pass into a class method multiple parameters, but it fails. I was able to pass in multiple parameters to a global function instead and that worked. Trying to pass in a variable amount of parameters to a class method instead fails!

Here is my code:

```
class TestParams {
    [int] $dummyVar

    TestParams() {
        $this.dummyVar = 0
    }

    [void]myMethod() {
        for ($index = 0; $index -lt $args.Count; $index++) {
            Write-Host $args[$index]
        }
    }
}

function testFunc() {
    for ($index = 0; $index -lt $args.Count; $index++) {
        Write-Host $args[$index]
    }
}

testFunc '1' '2' '3' # works

$myTestObj = New-Object TestParams
$myTestObj.myMethod "A" "B" "C" # fails
```

As you can see from running my code it gives error messages such as:

```
At C:\*****\testParams.ps1:25 char:21
+ $myTestObj.myMethod "A" "B" "C"
+                     ~~~
Unexpected token '"A"' in expression or statement.
```

I do not know what is causing this error! Can you guys help me debug this?

Comment: Method calls use parentheses and commas.

Comment: As Mike said, it's `$obj.MyMethod('A', 'B', 'C')` with methods, and `Invoke-Function 'A' 'B' 'C'` with (advanced) functions.

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare the parameters in the method definition:

```
[void]
myMethod( [array]$arguments ) {
    for ($index = 0; $index -lt $arguments.Count; $index++) {
        Write-Host $arguments[$index]
    }
}
```

Note that I intentionally changed the automatic variable name `args` to something else, otherwise it won't work.

In order to call the method, use the following syntax:

```
$myTestObj.myMethod(@('A', 'B', 'C'))
# or
$argument = 'A', 'B', 'C'
$myTestObj.myMethod($argument)
```

Comment: is [array] the same as [object[]]? I had a dynamic number of arguments to pass, each of which could contain multiple values, so I ended up using [object[]]. Would [array] have worked equally well here? Sorry not able to test it myself at this time.

Comment: @Blaisem either would have worked - all array types inherit from [array], and @() produces an [object[]] - so @() would satisfy either constraint:)

Answer (score 3):

**PowerShell [custom classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes) (PSv5+) work *more like C# code***, not like PowerShell functions and scripts:

- **Method / constructor declarations *as well as calls* must use *method* syntax**, i.e., `(...)` around a list of `,`-separated arguments rather than *command* syntax (*space*-separated arguments *without* enclosing `(...)`); e.g., if `.MyMethod()` had 3 distinct parameters:

  - `$obj.MyMethod('A', 'B', 'C')` instead of `$obj.MyMethod 'A' 'B' 'C'`
- **Any arguments you pass must bind to *formally declared parameters*** - there is *no* support for accessing arbitrary arguments via automatic variable`$Args`.<sup>[1]</sup>
- There is **no *implicit* output** behavior: Unless methods don't declare a return type or use `[void]`, they **must use `return`** to return a value.

[Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54876432/45375) shows how to implement your method with an open-ended number of arguments via an  *array* parameter, emulating the `$Args` functionality available only to *functions*.

---

<sup>[1] Due to a bug as of PowerShell Core 6.2.0-rc.1, `$Args` can unexpectedly be referenced in a method - despite not having been initialized - but always evaluates to an *empty array* - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9174).</sup>