# Correct parameters values not passed on to the function

Tags: powershell

I have a file called TestFunc.ps1. Its contents are as follows

```
Function TestFunc([string]$param1, [string]$param2)
{
    Write-Host "------------------"
    Write-Host $param1
    Write-Host $param2
    Write-Host "------------------"
}

TestFunc $param1 $param2
```

I called it as follows

```
C:\Test\TestFunc.ps1 "Hello" "World"
```

The output is as follows

```
------------------


------------------
```

I expect the output as

```
------------------
Hello 
World 
------------------
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to add a [Param](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-6) section to your script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameters are defined for the scope of the function, and not the script.

What you want is a [Param](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-6#parameters-in-scripts) section:

```
param ([string]$param1, [string]$param2)

function TestFunc([string]$param1, [string]$param2) {
    Write-Host "------------------"
    Write-Host $param1
    Write-Host $param2
    Write-Host "------------------"
}
TestFunc $param1 $param2
```

Of course, having duplicate variable names is misleading, but I it's just a test function. In your case, you wouldn't even need a function at all:

```
param ([string]$param1, [string]$param2)

Write-Host "------------------"
Write-Host $param1
Write-Host $param2
Write-Host "------------------"
```

Or alternatively:

```
param ([string]$param1, [string]$param2)

function TestFunc {
    Write-Host "------------------"
    Write-Host $param1
    Write-Host $param2
    Write-Host "------------------"
}
TestFunc
```

Or use the `$args` [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6#args), without defining any parameters at all:

```
function TestFunc {
    Write-Host "------------------"
    Write-Host $args[0]
    Write-Host $args[1]
    Write-Host "------------------"
}
TestFunc foo bar
```

Answer (score 1):

To *complement* [marsze's helpful and effective answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55225338/45375):

PowerShell has **two *largely equivalent* syntax forms for defining parameters** - leaving PSv5+ `class` definitions aside<sup>[1]</sup>:

<sup>Note: For brevity, the parameter lists are placed on a single line below; however,  both syntax forms allow placing individual parameters on their own line.</sup>

- **For *functions*** only:

  - **C/C#-like:** a **`,`-separated list** of parameter-variable declarations **inside `(...)` after the function *name* and *before* the opening `{`**; e.g.:

    ```
    function foo ($bar, $baz) {
      # ... 
    }
    ```
- For ***scripts*  and *functions too***, as well as ***script blocks*** (`{ ... }`, which are like *anonymous* functions):

  - **PowerShell-specific**: A **`,`-separated list** of parameter-variable declarations **inside `param(...)`**, which must be **the *first statement* inside the *body*** (apart from comments and `using` directives):

    ```
    # --- Script foo.ps1
    param($bar, $baz)

    # ...


    # --- Function
    # This example is fully equivalent to `foo ($bar, $baz) { ...` above.
    # Note that no () is needed after the function name.
    function foo {
      param($bar, $baz)
      # ...
    }

    # --- Script block
    & {
      param($bar, $baz)
      # ...
    } # arguments...
    ```

For brevity, the following **optional elements** were omitted above:

- **On individual parameter declarations**:

  - *Typing*; e.g., to declare parameter `$foo` as type `[int]` (`System.Int32`):

    - `[int] $foo`
  - *Parameter attributes*, typically, but not exclusively via the `[Parameter()]` attribute; among other things, the latter determines whether the associated parameter is *mandatory*; e.g.:

    - `[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [int] $foo`
- **Above the `param(...)` statement *only***:

  - The `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute, which makes a function or script an *advanced* one, with behaviors on par with (compiled) PowerShell *cmdlets* - see [about_Functions_Advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced)

In **simple (non-advanced) scripts and functions** it is **also an option *not to declare any parameters*** at all, in which **any arguments passed are contained in the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables)**, which is a regular PowerShell array (`[object[]]`).
You can even *combine* `$args` with declared parameters: `$args` then contains only those arguments that didn't bind to declared ones.

By contrast, in [*advanced* scripts and functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced), you are fundamentally only permitted to pass arguments that bind to *declared* parameters.

---

#### When to choose which syntax form:

- *Script files* and *script blocks* *must* use a `param(...)` statement - the C#-like syntax isn't available.
- *Functions* can *technically* use the C#-like syntax and the `param(...)` *interchangeably*, *except* if the `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute is needed, in which case only the `param(...)` syntax works.

  - That said, for consistency and easier extensibility (making a function an advanced one later), **the `param(...)` syntax is generally preferable**.
  - Also, **using the C#-like syntax frequently can more easily lead to *syntax confusion* when *invoking* a function**, given that PowerShell cmdlets and functions are invoked like *shell commands* (no parentheses, whitespace-separated arguments), not like C# *methods*; e.g., 
    `foo 1 2` (or `foo -bar 1 -baz 2`) rather than `foo(1, 2)`

---

<sup>[1] The method declarations in `class` definitions *must* use C#-like syntax, and no parameter attributes are supported (they're only supported on *properties*). Just like methods on native .NET types, class methods must also be *called* with method syntax - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54877446/45375) and help topic [about_Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes).</sup>

Comment: And then there's also `$args`. Not really a way of "defining" parameters, yes, but yet another possibility in this case.

Comment: Good point, @marsze, thanks - I've updated the answer to discuss `$args` too, and I've added a footnote re parameter syntax in `class` definitions.