# How does one Transform a Collection of Objects into a Collection of new Objects of another Type in Powershell?

Tags: linq, powershell, projection

Supposing I have a method that gets a collection of enums of my enum type `ProjectName` and a have a collection of `Server` objects I want to associate with those `ProjectName`s in a type called `Project`; how would I do this in a Powershell `Select-Object` (or some other equivalent of LINQ's `Select`).

The C# equivalent of what I want to produce in Powershell is this:

```
var servers = new[]
{
    new Server(/*someOtherProjectsCollection goes here*/),
    new Server(/*someOtherProjectsCollection goes here*/),
    new Server(/*someOtherProjectsCollection goes here*/)
};
var projects = GetProjectNames().Select(projectName => new Project(projectName, servers.Where(server => server.Projects.Any(serverProject => serverProject.Name == projectName))));
```

But what I have is this:

```
$servers = [Server]::new(/*someOtherProjectsCollection goes here*/), [Server]::new(/*someOtherProjectsCollection goes here*/), [Server]::new(/*someOtherProjectsCollection goes here*/)

$projects = (GetProjectNames()) | Select-Object {
    $selectedProjectName = $_

    return [Project]::new($_, ($servers | Where-Object { $_.projects.Where({ $_ -eq $selectedProjectName }).Count -gt 0 }))
}
```

When I try and read `$projects` back in Powershell LSE (whilst on a breakpoint after this last line), it just returns the code as a string and I can't even cast it to `[Project[]]`.  I think the problem might be with the use of curly braces with `Select-Object` but I'm not sure how else to create a new `Project` object within the `Select-Object`.

Comment: Replace `Select-Object` with `ForEach-Object`

Comment: As an aside:`GetProjectNames()` should be `GetProjectNames`, because PowerShell cmdlets and functions are invoked like _shell commands_ , not like _methods_. That is, no parentheses around the argument list, and _whitespace_-separated arguments (`,` constructs an _array_ as a _single argument_).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `ForEach-Object` instead of `Select-Object` to return a new `[Project]` instance for each project name; also, your code can be streamlined:

```
$projects = GetProjectNames | ForEach-Object {
    $projectName = $_
    [Project]::new(
      $projectName, 
      $servers.Where({ $_.projects -eq $projectName })
    )
}
```

- `Select-Object` is for creating new custom objects based on select properties from the input objects; by contrast, you're constructing a new, specific type instance from each input object, which must be done in a `ForEach-Object` call, where you explicitly control the output.
- `$_.projects -eq $projectName` as a conditional relies on PowerShell's ability to use `-eq` with an *array* as the LHS, in which case *filtering* is performed, and a filtered *subarray* is returned; since `.Where()` interprets the script block's output as a *Boolean*, an empty subarray is interpreted as `$false`, whereas one with at least one element is interpreted as `$true`.
- Also note that you don't need an explicit `return`, given PowerShell's *implicit output* behavior: since the newly constructed `[Project]` instance isn't assigned to a variable or sent elsewhere, it is automatically returned.

Comment: Excellent!  So with Powershell's ForEach-Object implicit return behaviour, will it return the first statement which returns something and doesn't assign it to anything, or the last (or some combination/Tuple of all within the statement block?)?

Comment: @MattArnold: It will return the output from _all_ statements (if they produce output at all and that output  isn't suppressed, captured, or redirected). While this can be convenient, it also constitutes a pitfall, because it's easy to accidentally produce output. Use `$null = ...` to discard unwanted output.

Comment: @MattArnold: P.S.: When a cmdlet / function / script / script block produces multiple outputs: if you _pipe them to another command_, they are sent _one by one_, _instantly_ (the enclosing cmdlet / function / ... doesn't have to finish running first); if you capture the outputs in a _variable_, they are collected in an `[object[]]` (`System.Object[]`) array; if there's only _one_ output object, it is captured as-is (no array is created).

Comment: Do you have to use `$null = ...` on preceding statements returning a value if you use `return` on the actual statement you intended to return?

Comment: @MattArnold: Yes. `return <val>` is just syntactic sugar for `<val>; return`, i.e., an (implicit) output statement followed by exiting the code unit at hand. The only exceptions are PSv5+ _custom classes_ created with the `class` keyword, whose methods work the way they do in C#: no implicit output, mandatory use of `return` - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54877446/45375